# RDS fslogix profile locked

Tags: rds, citrix

we are running an on-prem traditional RDS setup.

1. We are using fslogix for profiles - users are getting profile issues where the user profiles are unable to mount. Essentially getting logged in with temp user profiles.
2. We've discovered deleting the cloud cache of the user profile will fix when possible to delete that.
   Removed the following files in cloud cache:
   a. Profile_username.VHDX
   b. Rw.vhdx
3. However in some situations RW.vhdx isn't able to be deleted, "the file is in use".
4. The file is not mounted.
5. There are no uses/lock of the file in ProcessExplorer, resource monitor or ofview.
6. AV is off.

Short of restarting is there another way to release the lock on the file or determine what is holding the lock?

edit: using handle gives the following

```
C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Handle>handle.exe "D:\ProgramData\FSLogix\Cache\user1\RW.VHDX"

System             pid: 4      type: File          922C: D:\ProgramData\FSLogix\Cache\user1\RW.VHDX.meta
System             pid: 4      type: File          A1CC: D:\ProgramData\FSLogix\Cache\user1\RW.VHDX



C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Handle>handle.exe -c A1CC -p 4

A1CC: File  (---)   D:\ProgramData\FSLogix\Cache\user1\RW.VHDX
Close handle A1CC in System (PID 4)? (y/n) y
Error closing handle:
The handle is invalid.
```